# How to reuse a Rails template in ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I have a [rails app](http://vols.herokuapp.com) ([source](https://github.com/OneAcreCafe/volunteers)) that does scheduling. I am trying to reuse the [template for shifts tables](https://github.com/OneAcreCafe/volunteers/blob/master/app/views/shifts/_table.html.haml) between the shifts view and a mail message.

I would like to drop the links for a mail message, but am having difficulty with the logic. The HAML I have currently is:

```
%table#shift-table
  %tr
    %th Start
    ⋮
    %th Task
    - if defined? params
      %th.options

  - @shifts.each do |shift|
    %tr
      %td= shift.start
      ⋮
      %td= link_to_if(defined? params, shift.task.name, shift) if shift.task
      - if defined? params
        %td
          = link_to 'Show', shift, class: [:btn, 'btn-default']
          - if defined? can? and can? :update, shift
            = link_to 'Edit', edit_shift_path(shift), class: [:btn, 'btn-default']
          - if defined? can? and can? :destroy, shift
            = link_to 'Delete', shift, :method => :delete, :data => { :confirm => 'Are you sure?' }, class: [:btn, 'btn-default']
```

The `defined? params` is `true` in the mailer, so this doesn't work. When I try `params.nil?` or `params[:controller]`, I get:

```
undefined method `params' for #<ScheduleMailer:0xae5e520>
```

I should mention that I'm sending the emails from a [rake task](https://github.com/OneAcreCafe/volunteers/blob/master/lib/tasks/email.rake).

Answer (score 0):

You want to know if the view is being rendered from an controller or not

```
# Idiom for setting undefined value 
- params = params rescue {}
...
- if params[controller]
```

or can you just check if the